# How can I use select_related in rest framework?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-queryset, django-select-related

I am new in Django, I am creating a basic website where users can post some messages and add some tags to that post. I have 3 models `Person`, `Post`, and `Tag`. Using the `rest framework`, I created API for `Posts`, which should give me a list of posts with person's names and tags which posts relate with. For a small number of posts, this is working fine, but for large posts, it is taking too long to respond. Using `Django-toolbar` I am able to figure out too many queries are being fired, so I used `prefetch_related` and `select_related` in queryset. Here, a number of queries were reduced by half but still for foreign key relationship query is executing for each record. below is a sample of my code.

For getting 10 records it is firing 34 queries without using `prefetch_related` on `Tag` model. After using `prefetch_related` on `Tag`, it is 15 queries. Now for an individual post, it is firing query on `Person` with self-join. How can I reduce this number of queries?

```
# models.py
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200,unique=True)

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200,unique=True)
    friends = models.ManyToManyField("self", blank=True)

class Post(models.Model):
    person_id = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    text = models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)
    related_tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)


# serilizers.py
class PostSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    @staticmethod
    def setup_eager_loading(queryset):
        queryset = queryset.select_related("person_id").prefetch_related("related_tags")
        return queryset

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('url', 'id', 'text','related_tags','person_id')
        # fields = '__all__'
        depth = 1


#views.py
class PostViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = PostSerializer.setup_eager_loading(Post.objects.all())
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
```

Below is the list of queries with respective occurrence:

```
SELECT `myapp_post`.`id`, `myapp_post`.`person_id_id`, `myapp_post`.`text`, `myapp_person`.`id`, `myapp_person`.`name` 
FROM `myapp_post` INNER JOIN `myapp_person` ON (`myapp_post`.`person_id_id` = `myapp_person`.`id`)
LIMIT 10
```

Occurrence - 1 time

```
SELECT (`myapp_post_related_tags`.`post_id`) AS `_prefetch_related_val_post_id`, `myapp_tag`.`id`, `myapp_tag`.`name`
FROM `myapp_tag` INNER JOIN `myapp_post_related_tags` ON (`myapp_tag`.`id` = `myapp_post_related_tags`.`tag_id`)
WHERE `myapp_post_related_tags`.`post_id` IN (11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20)
```

Occurrence - 1 time

```
SELECT `myapp_person`.`id`, `myapp_person`.`name`
FROM `myapp_person` INNER JOIN `myapp_person_related_persons` ON (`myapp_person`.`id` = `myapp_person_related_persons`.`to_person_id`)
WHERE `myapp_person_related_persons`.`from_person_id` = 704692
```

Occurrence - 10 times for 10 records

Comment: Try `select_related("person")` instead of `person_id`.

Comment: @Alasdair It says me Invalid field name(s) given in select_related: 'person'. Choices are: person_id

Comment: Sorry, I misread your models. Normally, you would have `person = models.ForeignKey(Person)`, then the database column will be `person_id`. If you name the model field `person_id`, then the database column is `person_id_id`, which is a bit odd.

Comment: Please add the queries to you question.

Comment: @Alasdair yes, naming was my mistake. I have written here all the queries.

Comment: @Alasdair here I don't want to fire 3rd query which is firing for each record. how can I stop that?

Comment: I can't see what the third query is for. Is it fetching the friends for each person? If so you could add `person_id__friends` to the `prefetch_related()` call.

Comment: @Alasdair yes, 3 rd query is fetching friends for each person, but I don't need this while fetching the posts data. I mention id, name, person _id and related_tags and depth 1 in post serializer and for getting person and related_tags info with minimum queries ideally it should be 2 only, for that I used select related and prefetch related. I am unable to understand why self join is firing on Person table. Btw prefetch_related() on person_id__related_persons is firing only 3 queries.

Comment: you could try using `.defer('person_id__friends')`, but i am not sure it prevents the additional query. Maybe `.values` or `.values_list`?

Comment: @Akash Has your question been resolved?

Comment: @BenyaminJafari In my case, I didn't required to fetch person friends list along with post objects, so assigning person_id to PersonSerializer (without friends column) fixed query issue.